# Cant use variables received by ajax in for loop

Tags: php, ajax, for-loop, variables, integer

I'm creating a webpage that receives data from a database and then selects specific results from the array of results.

The initial and end entries to be selected are received from the POST variable and passed to a for loop which then selects the entries.

For some reason, even though this works:

```
//in php/movimientosJockeys.php

for($i = 0; $i <10; $i++)
{}
```

This doesn't

```
//in php/movimientosJockeys.php

$init = $_POST['init'];
$end= $_POST['end'];


$init = intval($init);
$end = intval($end);

for($i = $init; $i <$end; $i++)
{
//some code which crops between start and end of for loop
}
```

**UPDATE**

The for loop never stops and it therefore never crops the data it receives, the whole database is written to the page and this collapses it.

Both $init and $end are received from POST and they are written there by an ajax call. When var_dump() is called on them their values are int(0) and int(10)

I want the for loop to be able to receive a different starting and ending point when needed.

**UPDATE**

This is the ajax that sends the data

```
//The function is called here
list(0,10);



//This is the defined list() function

function list(initVal,endVal){

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/movimientosJockeys.php",
            data:{
                totalcarro: true,
                init: initVal,
                end: endVal
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('#tdbody').html(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Please show your JS and where the data it's sending is coming from.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Have you verified that `$init` and `$end` contain what you think they contain?

Comment: I have changed the question according to what you said, hope this helps to clarify

Comment: check variables is there any accessing problem

Comment: @AlexHowansky @JonStirling @sanjaya The changes have been made to the question, and answering to your questions, yes I have verified the contents of `$init and `$end` with `var_dump()` and they contain int(0) and int(10)

Answer (score -2):

```
$_POST['init'] = 5;
$_POST['end'] = 10;

$init = (int) $_POST['init'];
$end = (int) $_POST['end'];

for($i = $init; $i < $end; $i++)
{
    echo $i . " ";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.